# Excel formula if with or returns wrong value

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

Got this formula:

```
=IF(OR(CP67>1,CZ67>1,DI67>1,DR67>1),2,"")
```

It should return "2" if value larger than 1 is present in one of the 4 columns, but it return value "2" in all of my 300 rows.There are formulas behind all 4 columns in hand, but (displayed) values in columns are either a blank cell or a number ranging from 1 to 3. Whole sheet is formatted as "Standard" (and table), and all values is placed to the right in the cell (not text). 
This should be a no-brainer, but I'm lost. Anyone that can spot what's wrong? If I do a test of this in a colmplete blank wb/sh it works just fine!

Comment: Sounds like you have text-that-looks-like-numbers which are **always** 'greater than' true numbers.

Comment: On a cell where you are expecting 2, select cell and choose option `Evaluate formula` and check intermediate steps. You may find a clue as to why you are not getting expected results.

Comment: The fact that it works in a new sheet indicates one of 2 things - 1) you have settings that change the behaviour of the cells at a general level in this sheet or 2) there is some specific cell formatting (as indicated by the comment by Jeeped above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press F9, sounds like you have manual calculation on.

Comment: File -> Options -> Formulas -> Calculations, is set to "Automatic" in my Excel... (sorry if menus is not correct named, I'm using a Norwegian Excel).

Comment: Just read your question again, blanks return true in this case. might want to modify so blanks to contain 0, search and edit formulas to return as necessary. *Edit* Did a test with ="">1 this returns true and most likely the root of your issue.

Comment: Thanks, that was an eye-opener. I've been using formulas to not display value 0 when retreiving data to these columns, but now it don't seem like such a good idea... :-)